# How to pass Array of objects as an input parameter to kendo multliselect dropdown ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

As i'm new to Kendo implementation, I've got a requirement to pass array of object from javascript to Kendo multiselect dropdown ajax call as a input paramter, as  I have tried to pass array of objects, when i check at controller side the object was there, but the values are null, can some body can help me to get out of this issue

Here is my javascript code

```
function getValues()
{

var selectedfieldValue=[];
var kendoSelectedFieldValue = [];
 var AdvanceFilterQuery = {};
                        AdvanceFilterQuery.Id = 1;
                        AdvanceFilterQuery.Text = 'wer';
                        AdvanceFilterQuery.Status = true;
                        AdvanceFilterQuery.ShortValue = 'yes';
                        selectedfieldValue.push($(elem).text());
                        kendoSelectedFieldValue.push(AdvanceFilterQuery);


$('#selectpicker_Value).kendoMultiSelect({
            placeholder: "Select",
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            filter: "startswith",
            noDataTemplate: 'No Data!',
            height: 290,
            virtual: {
                itemHeight: 26,
            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "../Home/ActionMethod",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;",
                         data: function () {
                            return {
                                selectedType: fieldType,
                                selectedValue: selectedfieldValue,
                                operatorType: operatorType
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                requestEnd: function (e) {
                },
                schema: {
                    data: 'data',
                    total: 'total',
                    fields: [
                        { field: 'Id', type: 'number' },
                        { field: 'Text', type: 'string' }

                    ]
                },
                pageSize: 44,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true
            },

        });
}
```

Server side method:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ActionMethod(string selectedType, List<AdvanceFilterQuery> selectedValue, string operatorType)
{

}
```

Here in selectedValue i'm getting list of object, but values are null.

Exprcted need to get the list of object to server side please find the below link for issue..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code:

```
var selectedValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
     <List<AdvanceFilterQuery>>
                    (Request.Params.GetParamValueByKey<string>("selectedValue"));
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.